# Error while trying to upload to TestFlight

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testflight

I get the following while trying to upload a build to TestFlight:

'Invalid Profile: developer build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to true.'

Any ideas how to remedy this?

Just to add some more information, this app worked fine before I swapped out my iMac's HD...

Comment: "this app worked fine before I swapped out my iMac's HD"...oh, no biggie..just a hard drive swap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **Can Be Debugged** to true. Can Be Debugged is a user-friendly representation of get-task-allow.

Comment: where can I find that key? I do not have an entitlements plist file.

Comment: Update: I checked "Enable Entitlements" check box under 'target -> Summary, and it created the entitlements file for me, I then added get-task-allow and set the BOOL value to YES. It worked. Thanks